# Import emscripten generated module in Svelte

Tags: javascript, emscripten, svelte

I am trying to make a Svelte component containing canvas that would show emscripten-compiled webgl application inside.
In traditional html, it requires the following setup:

```
<script>
  var canv = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var Module = { canvas: canv };
</script>
<script src="index.js"></src>
```

The closest I have gotten to it was along these lines:

```
<script>
  let canv;
  let Module = { canvas: canv };
</script>

<svelte:head>
  <script src="index.js"></src>
</svelte:head>

<canvas bind:this={canv}></canvas>
```

Which does load the module in but index.js fails to initialize with some error:

```
exception thrown: TypeError: eventHandler.target is null,registerOrRemoveHandler
```

Which is basically index.js failing to see `Module` - this error remains the same if I do not initialize `Module` at all.

I understand I could play a bit with `MODULARIZE` compiler option (I have not looked into it yet) but as it is a webgl application, I would much prefer to let it run upon loading like in traditional html, that way I can focus on C++ without setting up the plumbing myself.

What is the correct way of doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of things going on here.

Firstly, a component is equivalent to a JavaScript module, which means that any variables declared inside a component are local to that component. If you need `Module` to be available globally, you should set it on `window`:

```js
window.Module = { canvas: canv };
```

Secondly, any time you're using `bind:this`, you need to wait until the component has actually mounted. The code inside a component's `<script>` runs before any DOM is created (since it often *determines* what DOM is created).

In this case, try using `onMount`:

```html
<script>
  import { onMount } from 'svelte';

  let canv;

  onMount(() => {
    window.Module = { canvas: canv };
  });
</script>

<svelte:head>
  <script src="index.js"></src>
</svelte:head>

<canvas bind:this={canv}></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks! Had to add an if block around secondary script to check whether the component is mounted first, but I can now pass the canvas correctly at least. ```eventHandler.target is null``` error still persists though, have to dig deeper.

Comment: I traced it down to emscripten calling ```document.querySelector( "#canvas" )``` which in this case returns null. Any idea about that?

Comment: ```<canvas id="canvas" bind:this={canv}></canvas>``` sorted that out. Cheers!